# Emacs 24.1: How do I restore i-search Ctrl-Y behavior from older versions?

Tags: emacs

In emacs 24.1, when you do Ctrl-Y in an interactive search, it yanks the kill buffer into the search string ("it pastes the clipboard contents" in any-other-app's language) and tries to
match it.

In the last 20 versions or so, pressing Ctrl-Y matches the rest of the current line.  I
have two very common use cases:

1. Match this line, revert the buffer, and search for the line
2. (less often:) Where else is this text in the buffer?

I tried modifying /lisp/isearch.el, switching the bindings for
isearch-yank-line (which I want) and isearch-yank-kill (which I'm fine binding
to the ridiculous \M-s\C-e key sequence). But I don't think this file even gets
picked up. But I don't think this file even gets loaded.  If I explicitly load
it, I still get the 24.1 behavior.

Here's my change:

```
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     (define-key isearch-mode-map    "\C-y" 'isearch-yank-line)
     (define-key isearch-mode-map "\M-s\C-e" 'isearch-yank-kill)
    ))
```

No change in the behavior.  I even tried hacking isearch.el, still no change.

This is on Windows btw, but I suspect it doesn't matter.

Could someone tell me how I can restore the old binding?

Answer (score 1):

what works for me is taking your hook and combining it with my own isearch-mode-hook.

(you could put this in `~/.emacs` … i go a bit further and keep separate modes in `~/.emacs.el/.modes.el`, then byte-compile that file, then `(load ".modes" t t)` to keep things a bit less cluttered.)

```
(setq isearch-mode-hook
      '(lambda nil
     (define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-y"   'isearch-yank-line)
     (define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-f"   'isearch-repeat-forward)
     (define-key isearch-mode-map "\C-t"    'isearch-toggle-regexp)))
```

works like a charm.  thanks for helping my get my ^Y back